# How do I get an editText to appear below my image, each time I take a picture?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layoutparams

I'm making a notepad type of app in which the user can take and place pictures in between the text as he is typing it.

In my app I have a `button` , `editText` and `imageView`. When it starts, there is only the `button` and an `editText`. The user types into the `editText` and when he presses the `button`, the camera opens. The taken picture gets placed right under the `editText` (under the last line entered by the user). Under the picture a new `editText` appears and the user can enter text into this. When he presses the button again another picture gets taken, placed below the second `editText` and a third `editText` is available to the user to enter text.

So each time the user takes a picture by pressing the button, a new `editText` appears under the image. This keeps looping, allowing the user to enter both text and images, as many images and paragraphs as he wants.

But this isn't happening. I'm only able to enter text once and take 1 picture. No second `editText` ever appears. What's going wrong here.

The code for alternating `editText` and `imageView` is located in  `onActivityResult()`

**mainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nirvan.cameraexample3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{


ImageView myImage;
EditText textVar;
int flag=0;             //flag==0 means place img below text, ==1 means below textVar

private String pictureImagePath = "";
Uri outputFileUri;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button imgButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);


    View.OnClickListener imgButtonClickListener=new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";
            File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            pictureImagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName;
            File file = new File(pictureImagePath);
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
        }
    };
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(imgButtonClickListener);


}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.d("TAG","CUSTOOOM");
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    myImage=new ImageView(this);
    myImage.setId(+1);




    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        File imgFile = new File(pictureImagePath);
       if (imgFile.exists())
        {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
           // myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTest);

            //this code ensures the imageView is placed below the editText
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            if(flag==0)
               {
                   relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.text);
                   flag=1;
               }
            else if(flag==1)
                relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textVar.getId());

            //myImage.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
            relativeLayout.addView(myImage,relativeParams);
            //
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


            //place the new editText below the imgaeView just placed
            relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, myImage.getId());
            textVar=new EditText(this);
            textVar.setId(+2    );
            relativeLayout.addView(textVar,relativeParams);
            textVar.setText("NEW");

        }
    }//






}



}
```

**mainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.cameraexample3.MainActivity">





<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="IMG"
    android:id="@+id/imgButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgButton"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE-** Taking Petrumo's suggestions I have revised the code. Although it's still not working the way it should. After taking the first image, a second `editText` is not being displayed under the image. 
    I have made sure that the `id`s for the `textView` and `imageView` are different for each iteration of the method.

**onActivityResult() updated**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.d("TAG","CUSTOOOM");
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    myImage=new ImageView(this);
    myImage.setId(id1++);
    textVar.setId(id2++);




    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        File imgFile = new File(pictureImagePath);
       if (imgFile.exists())
        {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
           // myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTest);

            //this code ensures the imageView is placed below the editText
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            if(flag==0)
               {
                   relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.text);
                   flag=1;
               }
            else if(flag==1)
                relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textVar.getId());




            //myImage.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
            relativeLayout.addView(myImage,relativeParams);
            //
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


            //place the new editText below the imgaeView just placed
            relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, myImage.getId());
            textVar=new EditText(this);
            //textVar.setId(id2++);

            relativeLayout.addView(textVar,relativeParams);
            textVar.setText("NEW");

        }
    }//






}
```

**UPDATE2:** So I simply replaced my code inside `onActivityResult` with Petrumo's ..and it works. The `editText`s appear one below the other. But when I insert the `imageView` code , the app crashes right after taking the picture.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if(textVar != null)
    {
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textVar.getId());
    }
    else
    {
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.text);
    }

    myImage=new ImageView(this);
    myImage.setId(id1++);
    //set image

        File imgFile = new File(pictureImagePath);
        if (imgFile.exists() && requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            relativeLayout.addView(myImage, relativeParams);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


        }

    //



    textVar=new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    textVar.setId(id2++);
    relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, myImage.getId());
    relativeLayout.addView(textVar, relativeParams);
    textVar.setText("NEW");
    relativeLayout.addView(textVar, relativeParams);




}
```

**Log**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.nirvan.cameraexample3, PID: 27598
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.nirvan.cameraexample3/com.example.nirvan.cameraexample3.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3432)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3564)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3417)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3393)
                                                                                   at com.example.nirvan.cameraexample3.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:105)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5446)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3428)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: What about creating a list with an adapter and adding a new empty row every time the user adds a new photo? You will have to save the new row only if there is datas in it and you're done :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley  At this stage I'm not concerned with saving the data, only with displaying it. Since there's no way of knowing beforehand how many images the user will take and hence how many imageViews are required, I'm adding the imageViews dynamically.

Comment: you don't need to save datas to use my solution, you will simply have a list where everything is stored and then you will add an empty entry on save to show the empty line :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code used:

- using of the same id
  textVar.setId(+2    );

this should be something

textVar.setId(id++);

where id is a global variable

- the same needs to be applied to the image id, it needs to be unique and used by the next one if you want to place it bellow

I simplified your solution and made it working, you can use it as a base and add your image in between:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
 (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  if(textVar != null)
  {
    relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textVar.getId());
  } else {
    relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.text);
  }

  textVar=new EditText(MainActivity.this);
  textVar.setId(id++);
  textVar.setText("NEW");


 relativeLayout.addView(textVar, relativeParams);
```

A simpler way, if you only want to add them below is to use LinearLayout with orientation vertical, or a more elegant solution to change it to a list with adapter as suggested in the comment.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestions, but the code still doesn't seem to be working like it should. I have updated my question to include the revised code as per your answer. Please have a look.

Comment: try to use the textVar.setId(id2++); where you commented it out instead, also if you noticed, I used (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); otherwise the MATCH_PARENT for the height it will use the entire screen. If you still can't make it work, try to start from my example and add it there, or switch to LinearLayout

Comment: Okay I copied your code and added the imageView code to it. Although now  it crashes as soon as I take a picture. I've checked it multiple times and I can't figure out where the problem is. Please help.

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: maybe because you are adding the same item twice? relativeLayout.addView(textVar, relativeParams);
    textVar.setText("NEW");
    relativeLayout.addView(textVar, relativeParams);